Позволяют ли правила русского языка обособлять слово "Вам" (Например, "Я, Вам, пишу..) для показателя наивысшего уважения?
В моей голове есть четкое убеждение, что раньше использовали такую форму пунктуации, и она считалась нормой для обращения к высокопоставленному лицу, однако, когда я сейчас полезла в интернет, не нашла подтверждение своим словам.

В литературе такое, вроде, не встречается. Отчего, Вы, считаете, что так нужно писать?

Нет! Слово вам - это слово, которое отвечает незнакомых лиц и также множествное число (например: людей). Оно не отвечает хороший или плохой.

В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в Справке.

Несколько несогласованный текст.
